# Preterite of ser and ir

Tags: verbos, etimología, tiempos-verbales

## Español

Pretérito de *ser*:

> fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fuisteis, fueron

Pretérito de *ir*:

> fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fuisteis, fueron

¿Cómo han evolucionado los verbos "ser" e "ir" para tener la misma conjugación en el pretérito (y también en el imperfecto y el futuro de subjuntivo)? ¿Y por qué las formas en el pretérito empiezan por "fu-"?

---

## Inglés

Preterite of *ser*:

> fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fuisteis, fueron

Preterite of *ir*:

> fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fuisteis, fueron

How did the verbs *ser* and *ir* evolve to have the same conjugation in the preterite (and also in the imperfect and future subjunctive)? And why do their preterite forms begin with *fu-*?

Comment: I'm not sure if this in an example of ["suppletion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) or an example of the opposite of suppletion \-: There's probably a good question for [the linguistics site](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) in it though!

Comment: I am editing this question to be entirely in English, instead of a mix of Spanish and English. If you believe an exception should be made for this question, please weigh in on the meta discussion about this (and similar posts): http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/86/12

Comment: Portuguese follows the same pattern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Español

Lo he oído explicado así:

El pretérito de "ser" viene de la versión del latín de [*esse*](http://www.math.osu.edu/~econrad/lang/lvesse.html), que usa la raíz 'fui'.

La historia va de que "ir" es irregular en el sentido de que estaba compuesto de múltiples verbos, y por tanto toma su pretérito del latín "*esse*".

- El presente, pretérito, subjuntivo del latín *[vadere](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb%3avidere)*.
- El infinitivo del latín *[ire](http://www.math.osu.edu/~econrad/lang/lvire.html)*.
- El condicional y el futuro vienen del infinitivo.

---

## Inglés

I've heard it explained this way:

The preterite of *ser* is from the latin version of [*esse*](http://www.math.osu.edu/~econrad/lang/lvesse.html), which uses the 'fui' root

The story goes that *ir* is irregular in the sense it was composed of multiple verbs, and therefore borrows its preterite form from the latin *esse*.

- Present, preterite, subjunctive from Latin *[vadere](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb%3avidere)*.
- Infinitive from Latin *[ire](http://www.math.osu.edu/~econrad/lang/lvire.html)*.
- Conditional and future are from infinitive.

Comment: Ah yes well the composition of *ir* from multiple verbs is definitely a case of *suppletion*. The use of some forms in multiple verbs is something I'm not sure there's a term for.

Comment: I think the second link (vadere) is wrong - I get the conjugation table of the verb videre (to see).

Comment: `The preterite of ser is from the latin version of esse, which uses the 'fui' root` You are just restating the presupposition from the question.

Comment: Although it is all true, it is not an *answer* to the original question. It is just the same said in different wording.

Comment: Does the preterite of *ir* come from Latin *vadere*? It reads *fui* instead of something similar to *vasi* (Latin active indicative present perfect).

Answer (score 1):

Both *ser* and *ir* are suppletive verbs, which means that their conjugations are the result of multiple verbs merging together in the past, some conjugations taken from one root verb, and some from the other. It so happens that one of the root verbs was shared by both of these: Latin *esse*, some of whose conjugations began *fu-*. Note, *esse* itself was formed by suppletion of two pre-latin verbs, see the following chart:

[image]

Now, the question of why *ir* suppleted with *esse* ("to be") is a semantic one, and non-rigourously one can imagine how "I was [there]", "I may be [there]" etc (*esse*) might come to mean the same as "I went [there]", "I may go [there]" etc (*ire*):

> for *ire* + *esse*: if you ‘are’ somewhere, it follows that you ‘went’ there. For example, you can say “I’ve never been to Barcelona” instead of “I’ve never gone to Barcelona”.
>
> - http://spanishlinguist.us/2017/02/why-ser-and-ir-are-so-irregular/

---

Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/are-the-english-words-essence-and-essential-related-to-the-spanish-word-ser